# ECDSA adaptor signing and decryption

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature

I am trying to understand [this article](https://medium.com/crypto-garage/adaptor-signature-on-ecdsa-cac148dfa3ad). Can someone explain to me how the ECDSA adaptor signing is work?

From the article:

1.
ECDSA adaptor signing
$$s' = (H(m) + R t p)r^{-1}$$

As I understand this is standard formula where $x = t p$ - is a private key for the signature s'. So public key is $P = t p G$

2.
Decryption ECDSA adaptor signature:
$$s = s' t^{-1} =  (H(m) + R t p)(rt)^{-1}$$

**I can't understand this.** Because it follows that:
$$s = s' t^{-1} =  (H(m) + R t p)(rt)^{-1} = (H(m) t^{-1} + R p)r^{-1}$$

But this is not standard formula for ECDSA signature ((
It should be
$$s = (H(m) + R p)r^{-1}$$

I don't think the article is wrong. Most likely I'm missing something. Can anyone help with understanding these formulas?

Comment: I'm confused too. The article claims $R'=Rt=rT$, where $T=tG$, which would only make sense if $R=rG$. But $R$ is not $rG$ and is not a point, $R$ is the x-coord of the point $rG$.